# Getting the result of a Case statement from SQL back to the application

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, case

I have a form that users can use to enter a serial number to see if a part is still under warranty or not.

[image: warranty search]

When they click the search button it connects to the database and runs my stored procedure that searches for the serial number they entered and checks a `DATETIME` column called `OFF_WARRANTY` which is the date until which the part is still under warranty. Whether or not that date is before or after `@today` determines if the part is still under warranty.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WarrantyLookup] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @serialNumber VARCHAR(150),
    @warrantyStatus VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @today DATE
    SET @today = GETDATE()

    IF(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM <serial number table> WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = @serialNumber) = 1
        SELECT OFF_WARRANTY,
            CASE
                WHEN OFF_WARRANTY >= @today THEN 'In warranty'
                WHEN OFF_WARRANTY < @today THEN 'Out of warranty'
                WHEN OFF_WARRANTY IS NULL THEN 'none'
                ELSE 'multiple'
            END
        FROM <serial number table>
        WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = @serialNumber
END
```

A serial number can be associated with multiple items in our system so the first thing I do is use `Count()` to make sure there's only 1. Then I'm trying to determine the items' warranty status and I made an output variable for that called `@warrantyStatus`.

The thing I'm not sure about is how exactly to set `@warrantyStatus` to the result of my `CASE` statement. In my mind I just want to do something fairly straightforward like:

```
SET @warrantyStatus = <the result of my CASE statement>
```

But I don't know how to type that, exactly? I showed a senior developer in my department and he said something about using a `SqlDataReader` and then doing `if(rdr.HasRows)` but didn't really clarify how. Can I use a `SqlDataReader` to read the results of my `CASE` statement?

I appreciate any help anyone can offer. I feel like I'm almost certainly over-complicating it, but I'm just not connecting the last dots to make this work.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: So you also need OFF_WARRANTY ?

Comment: Use a function and you can return the value as a query.  For that matter, you could just create a view instead of a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost exactly right. Except you can't mix a query that returns data when setting variables. If you needed the other fields then I guess the most performant way would be to SELECT the results into a @TempTable.

```
SELECT 
   @warrantyStatus = 
       CASE
            WHEN OFF_WARRANTY >= @today THEN 'In warranty'
            WHEN OFF_WARRANTY < @today THEN 'Out of warranty'
            WHEN OFF_WARRANTY IS NULL THEN 'none'
            ELSE 'multiple'
       END
```

Conversely, the SET operation would also work here.

```
 SET @warrantyStatus=
    (
       SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN OFF_WARRANTY >= @today THEN 'In warranty'
                WHEN OFF_WARRANTY < @today THEN 'Out of warranty'
                WHEN OFF_WARRANTY IS NULL THEN 'none'
                ELSE 'multiple'
            END
        FROM <serial number table>
        WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = @serialNumber
    )
```

Here you can insert into a @Table to return the other rows.

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE
(
    OFF_WARRANTY NVARCHAR(50),
    CalcWarranty NVARCHAR(50)
)


IF(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM <serial number table> WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = @serialNumber) = 1
INSERT @Result
SELECT 
    OFF_WARRANTY,
    CalcWarranty = 
    CASE
        WHEN OFF_WARRANTY >= @today THEN 'In warranty'
        WHEN OFF_WARRANTY < @today THEN 'Out of warranty'
        WHEN OFF_WARRANTY IS NULL THEN 'none'
        ELSE 'multiple'
    END
FROM <serial number table>
WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = @serialNumber

SELECT @warrantyStatus = CalcWarranty FROM @Result

SELECT
    OFF_WARRANTY
FROM
    @Result
```

Comment: thanks @Ross, I used a slightly modified version of the SET example you suggested and it's working perfectly!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a view and use a `select`?

```
CREATE VIEW v_warranty_stuff as
    SELECT SERIAL_NUMBER, OFF_WARRANTY,
           (CASE WHEN OFF_WARRANTY >= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) THEN 'In warranty'
                 WHEN OFF_WARRANTY < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) THEN 'Out of warranty'
                 WHEN OFF_WARRANTY IS NULL THEN 'none'
                 ELSE 'multiple'
            END) as warrantystatus
    FROM <serial number table>;
```

Then you can simply call:

```
select warranty_status
from v_warranty_stuff
where SERIAL_NUMBER = @serialNumber;
```